# How to make a correct xpath?

Tags: python, dom, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from robots.txt. But when it comes to xpath selectors they doesn't work. For example i am trying to select xpath by `response.xpath('/urlset/url[1]/loc').get()` , but there is no result. In firefox and in scrapy shell the source code corresponds(in chrome no). The robots.txt file that i am trying to scrape is [sciencopen](https://www.scienceopen.com/sitemap.xml)

Comment: Do you need the text from the `<loc>` tag?. If yes, then try `response.xpath('/urlset/url[1]/loc/text').get()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KrupalVaghasiya:  That won't work due to the default namespace.  See duplicate link for how to deal with XML namespaces in XPath.